# Is there any standard procedure to quantify the number of genocide victims?

Tags: genocide

What procedure is generally followed to count the number of victims in genocides?

Is there any standard procedure in practice?

Who counts this? The post-genocide government or UNO or any other agency?

Answer (score 2):

For **legal** purposes, the number does not really matter. The [definition of genocide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocide#International_law) is the combination of overt acts with the intent behind them. Just a few murders would be enough if the goal was to destroy a people.

That leaves the **historical and political** judgement, which differs from case to case based on available data. For the [German Holocaust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocaust_victims), there is the combination of surviving German documents and the comparison of before-and-after numbers. The latter has problems, but for large populations the measuring of [excess mortality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortality_displacement) can give valid statistical results. Compare the estimates for the [Armenian genocide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_genocide), which have a much higher spread.

Comment: Most of the acts in the definition do not involve directly killing people, either